# CASSANDRA issue 3770 COPY FROM

Tags: python, cassandra, copy

Anybody know how solved problem with this error:

```
This platform lacks a functioning sem_open implementation, therefore, the required synchronization primitives needed will not function, see issue 3770.
```

I got this message when I try use COPY FROM.
Currently I use Cassandra 3.7 and Python 2.7.6

Comment: What platform are you using? I believe it's an error with Python.

Comment: I managed to solve this error, it is solution: Add following to /etc/fstab:
tmpfs   /dev/shm    tmpfs   defaults        0   0
and later sudo mount /dev/shm